# Which OS should I install on an old Raspberry Pi 2b

Tags: pi-2

I have an old Raspberry Pi 2b. My SD went nuts, so I have to install OS again.
I tried raspbian 9, but everything seem soooooo sloooooow.

I would love kodi, but I can cope with just a media player (VLC?), a browser and a torrent manager.

I know any answer would be a suggestion and not a straight fact, maybe you can backup with experience, but I just wouldn't like to try six or seven OS to find the right one, I suppose out there has the answer to this

Comment: Raspbian will generally be as fast as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is Linux.

All will be slow on a slow machine.